# Put HTML into Outlook email for campaign

Tags: html, html-email, mailchimp

I'm trying to send an HTML email campaign like MailChimp or Constant Contact but I cannot figure out how. I have an index.html I made on a website called InkBrush.com but I can't figure out how to send it as an email. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: Maybe the question on this site can point you in the right direction: http://superuser.com/q/213825/500869

Comment: You need to use a server side programming language (like PHP, .NET, etc) in order to send email from your website. If you want to send email through a provider like MailChimp or Constant Contact you may be able to use javascript AJAX to submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a few emails you want to sent with a email client manually try opening up the HTML file you have and press "CTRL + A " Then "CTRL + C" which will copy all the content to the clipboard. Then go to the email client and press "CTRL + P", this often will allow you to paste the html content into the email. However, it might not look picture perfect because Email clients don't support the whole range of W3C complaint XHTML.

You can also check out more in [this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/how-to-send-an-html-email-from-gmail/) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You have different available options and depending on your knowledge level you can choose between them.

I recommend you to use macros, anyway, remember that there are limitations and maybe, you can't send the same html that you wrote.

Here you have an explanation with the different methods:

https://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails/